# Second syzygy modules over rings , satisfying $(S_1)$ and $(G_0)$ , are reflexive

Tags: commutative-algebra, homological-algebra, cohen-macaulay, gorenstein

Let $(R,\mathfrak m,k)$ be a Noetherian local ring  such that $R_P$ is Gorenstein for every minimal prime ideal $P$ of $R$ and $\text{depth }R_P\ge 1$ whenever $ht (P)\ge 1$.

If $0\ne M$ is a finitely generated $R$-module such that for some integers $s,t\ge 1$, there is an exact sequence $0\to M\to R^t\to R^s$, then how to prove that $M$ is reflexive ?

My thoughts: I need to prove $M\cong M^{**}$, or equivalently, $\text{Ext}^i_R(\text{Tr}M,R)=0$ for $i=1,2$, where $\text {Tr}(-)$ denotes Auslander transpose. Firstly, $M$ is a submodule of a finite free module, hence $M$ is torsion-less, so $\text{Ext}^1_R(\text{Tr}M,R)=0$ . Unfortunately, I'm unable to show $\text{Ext}^2_R(\text{Tr}M,R)=0$. Please help.

Answer (score 2):

Let $R$ be a left and right Noetherian ring $R$, and consider a finitely generated left $R$-module $M$. Bass in [[Bass 1960](https://doi.org/10.1090/S0002-9947-1960-0157984-8), p. 478] states that $M$ is a second syzygy module if and only if it is of the form $\operatorname{Hom}_R(N,R)$ for a finitely generated right $R$-module $N$. (In the commutative case, you can also look at the Lemma and the Remark in [[Bass 1963](https://doi.org/10.1007/BF01112819), p. 26]).

Now suppose that $R$ is commutative and Noetherian. Bass in [[Bass 1963](https://doi.org/10.1007/BF01112819), Prop. 6.1] proved that $R$ satisfies $S_1$ and $G_0$ (in your notation) if and only if the dual of every finite generated $R$-module is reflexive (see also [[Ischebeck 1969](https://doi.org/10.1016/0021-8693(69)90090-8), (4.7); [Hartshorne 1994](https://doi.org/10.1007/BF00960866), Cor. 1.8]).

Combining these two results, we have:

**Proposition.** *Let $R$ be a commutative Noetherian ring satisfying $S_1$ and $G_0$. Then, an $R$-module is a second syzygy module if and only if it is reflexive.*

If you want a single reference for this fact, you can use [[Hartshorne 1994](https://doi.org/10.1007/BF00960866), Prop. 1.7].

*Remark.* Bass's original definition for syzygy modules [[Bass 1963](https://doi.org/10.1007/BF01112819), §8] has a shift by 1.

*Remark.* The notation for $S_1$ and $G_0$ you have in mind I think matches that in [[Hartshorne 1994](https://doi.org/10.1007/BF00960866), §1]. As I mentioned in [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4144695/116766) there are other definitions for $G_r$ in the literature.