# Injection into double dual is isomorphism away from codimension $\geq 2$ subscheme

Tags: algebraic-geometry, schemes, projective-schemes

Let $X$ be a quasi-projective integral scheme and let $F$ be a torsion-free coherent sheaf over $X$. Then there is an injective map
$$\phi\colon F\hookrightarrow F^{\vee\vee}.$$
Moreover, in my situation it is known that $F^{\vee\vee}$ is locally free. Is it true that $\phi$ is an isomorphism away from a closed subscheme of codimension $\geq 2$? Of course, this holds true if $X$ is normal, but is it also true for non-normal $X$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe the following is true:

**Proposition.** *Let $X$ be a locally noetherian scheme that is Gorenstein in codimension one and satisfies Serre's condition $S_1$. Then, for every torsion-free coherent sheaf $F$ on $X$, the natural morphism*
$$\phi\colon F \longrightarrow F^{\vee\vee}$$
*is injective, and is an isomorphism away from a closed subscheme of codimension $\ge2$.*

*Proof.* We first note that $\phi$ is injective since $X$ is Gorenstein in codimension zero and satisfies $S_1$, and hence "torsion-free" and "torsion-less" are equivalent [[Vasconcelos 1968](https://doi.org/10.1090/S0002-9939-1968-0237480-2), Thm. A.1].

We now prove that $\phi$ is an isomorphism away from a closed subscheme of codimension $\ge 2$. Note that the non-isomorphism locus is closed since it is the support of $\operatorname{coker}(\phi)$, which is closed since $\operatorname{coker}(\phi)$ is coherent. It suffices to show that $\phi$ is an isomorphism in codimension one, and hence it suffices to show that if $R$ is a Gorenstein local ring, then all torsion-less $R$-modules are reflexive. But this follows from [[Jans 1961](https://doi.org/10.1090/S0002-9939-1961-0137743-9), Cor. 1.3]. $\blacksquare$

*Remark.* The assumption that $X$ is Gorenstein in codimension one and satisfies $S_1$ is Marinari's condition $G_1$ [[Marinari 1972](http://www.numdam.org/item/RSMUP_1972__48__67_0/), Def. 4.5]. I have not used this terminology in the statement because there is more than one definition known as $G_1$ in the literature (cf. [[Ischebeck 1969](https://doi.org/10.1016/0021-8693(69)90090-8), Def. 3.16] and [[Reiten and Fossum 1970](https://mathscinet.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=289503), p. 142]).

Comment: Thank you very much for your nice answer!